# How to resolve "ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV" in docker container

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault

I have a Node.js application deployed to a docker container with `fluent-ffmpeg`, `@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg`, and `@ffprobe-installer/ffmprobe`.

Here is the `fluent-ffmpeg` init script:

```
import ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);

export default ffmpeg;
```

This gets used to take a snapshot of a video and save that image to file:

```
ffmpeg('ism manifest here')
        .inputOption(`-ss timestamp`)
        .outputOptions([
            '-vframes 1',
            '-vf crop=640:230:320:490,eq=saturation=0:contrast=1000,negate'
        ])
        .output('test.png')
        .run();
```

Whenever *any* configuration of ffmpeg command is run, it nearly instantaneously fails with:

```
Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV
     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:180:22)
     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
```

I have attempted to raise the memory and CPU usage limits of the server in the docker-compose file:

```
...
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.75'
          memory: 2G
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 1G
```

But nothing has worked. Running this on my local machine works just fine. Help?

UPDATE:

I just attempted running a small dockerized ffmpeg test script on its own in its own brand new container. Same issue. So, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my server's configuration.

Comment: Without your Dockerfile it seems too difficult to start debugging

Comment: @pierpy Good point. I just added the server docker-compose config and dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there's some sort of issue with using the binary provided by `@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg` in Docker.

I instead went the route that I found elsewhere, which is to run

```
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg -y
```

in the dockerfile. This installs `ffmpeg` and adds it to the Linux PATH, allowing it to be picked up by `fluent-ffmpeg` automatically. Alternatively, you could also still run `ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('/usr/bin/ffmpeg');` manually.

`ffmpeg` now works like a charm.